# Pandas dataframe groupby to a new dataframe with grouped observation in the same row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, aggregate

I'm building a `df` in which observations are grouped `two by two` as below:

```
group user amount
ALFA   x    2.3
ALFA   y    1.9
BETA   w    1.8
GAMMA  z    1.3
BETA   s    0.9
GAMMA  q    0.4
```

I want a new `df` with user belonging to the same group to be in the same row, as shown below:

```
user1 user2 amount1 amount2
 x      y     2.3     1.9
 w      s     1.8     0.9
 z      q     1.3     0.4
```

Values don't need to be sorted in any certain way.

I've tried with `df.groupby('group').agg(['min','max'])`, but this sorts users in alphabetical order instead of corresponding couple user-amount.

Does anybody know how to solve this with pandas?

Comment: Are there always two users in each group for the observation?

Comment: Yes, always two in each group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group the dataframe on column `group` then inside a list comprehension using `np.hstack` horizontally stack the corresponding `users` and `amount` and create a new dataframe:

```
d = pd.DataFrame([
       np.hstack([g['user'], g['amount']]) for _, g in df.groupby('group')],
       columns=['user1', 'user2', 'amount1', 'amount2'])
```

Result:

```
  user1 user2  amount1  amount2
0     x     y      2.3      1.9
1     w     s      1.8      0.9
2     z     q      1.3      0.4
```